# Is there why to change direction by hotkey in Eclipse search?

Tags: eclipse

When we find something in Eclipse we use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and find the word.

But the *Direction* search option is so annoying, I want bi-direction search not forward or backward.

Is there way to change the option?

Comment: how should the bi-direction search work? Search one line up, one down, two up, two down, three up, and so on? Do you just want to search the complete file? Then try 'wrap search'

Comment: Did you checked my options in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Using `Ctrl + H` ( Or Search -> File) you can search a file in `File name patterns` and search will return occurrences in all file.

Also you can mark what you want to search and then click Search -> Text - File and you will get it.